# How to send keystrokes before interactive shell to automate Linux serial port login with GNU screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, serial-port, expect

I often have to login into Linux devboards with known fixed usernames and password via the serial port.

The normal commands are:

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 115200
```

and then inside `screen` the session looks like:

```
<enter>
somehost login: root<enter>
Password: root<enter>
user@host#
```

How to automate this login procedure so I don't have to type the username and password every time?

I can also use `expect` if needed. I've tried:

```
expect -c "spawn screen /dev/ttyS${1:-0} ${2:-115200}; send "\r"; expect \"* login: \"; send \"root\"; expect \"Password: \"; send \"root\"; interact"
```

but my `expect` skills don't quite cut it and this just hangs.

Also, if I logoug and login immediately, the second time it does not ask for the password and goes directly to the prompt:

```
user@host#
```

so hopefully the script should also take that into account. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464887/modify-expect-based-ssh-script-to-work-on-machines-that-dont-require-a-password

Similar question for SSH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh

Comment: I believe something like this would work: `screen -X at "ttyS0" stuff "root\n$PASSWORD\n"`, but I don't have a serial port to test it on.

Comment: @kasperd I tried some `-X` briefly but couldn't get it to work. I might try some more later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can help to debug `expect` by adding option `-d`. In your example you would see that you are doing `"...send "\r"..."` which is evaluated by the shell as `...send r...` because `\r` is on its own outside the doublequotes.  Try changing that to `send \"\r\"` as in the other cases. You also need to put a similar carriage-return at the end of each send: `send \"root\r\"`.

It would cleaner to write a small shell script file, or use single quotes, converting to doublequotes for the `${1:-0}` that need interpolating:

```
expect -c 'spawn screen /dev/ttyS'"${1:-0} ${2:-115200}"'; send \r; expect " login: ";...'
```

This complete script (without using the shell) also deals with the already logged in case:

```
#!/bin/expect --
set tty 0
set baud 115200
if { $argc >= 1 } {
 set tty [lindex $argv 0]
}
if { $argc >= 2 } {
 set baud [lindex $argv 1]
}
spawn screen /dev/ttyS$tty $baud
send \r
expect {
      "login: " {
           send root\r
           expect "Password: "
           send root\r
       }
       "#" 
    }
interact
```